# How to reconsider MSE metric when doing target engineering through a logarithm?

Tags: metric

I am a user of Keras with Python, if I know some mathematics I am not very good at algebraic transformation.

The context is the following. 
I am trying to reproduce the performances from a paper. In this paper, each individual has his own model: a neural network with the pattern 8-5-7-1. All these models reached a *MSE* of 100.
In my work, I do not use the same variables, so I found a different pattern.
I considered 3 individuals (3 models). I have remarked models (of the same pattern) learn better when the skewness of the target is lower. /!\ The target is not transformed at all at this moment.
In concrete terms:

1. Model 1: skewness 0.41 manage to learn until 100 *MSE* (reached the goal)
2. Model 2: skewness 0.66 manage to learn until 200 *MSE* not less (do not reach the goal)
3. Model 3: skewness 0.31 manage to learn until 80 *MSE* (beyond the reached goal)

So this is why I am thinking about making a target engineering by using the logarithm of any base (while it reduces the skewness it is ok). Nevertheless, it transforms the reached metric: 100 *MSE* as the maximum threshold. And I am pretty sure I cannot just compute *log(MSE)*.
I searched the formula, of course: $ MSE = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^{n}(y_{i}-\bar{y}_i)^{2} $

But I am not able with my limited skills to reconsider it correctly. I need help.
So *MSE* is dependent on the *n* observations of the dataset, more the logarithm transformation on *y*. How can I implement a function that will allow transforming the new form of *MSE* obtained through a logarithmic transformation in order to compare it with the previous goal: 100 *MSE* on a non-transformed target?

Answer (score 1):

If you log-transform your targets before training, i.e. replace `y_train` with `np.log(y_train)`, then you need to adjust for this with both your error metric and your loss function.

The `y_pred` predictions you obtain from training are effectively log-transformed, and so you should undo the log transform with an exponential function prior to computing MSE, i.e.

```
mean_squared_error(y_test,np.exp(y_pred))
```

Note that I did not exponentiate the `y_test` here - I'm assuming you did not log-transform `y_test` because there's no reason to.

Another option is to leave `y_pred` as is, and ALSO log-transform `y_test`:

```
mean_squared_error(np.log(y_test),y_pred)
```

However, this is effectively comparable to using the MSLE (mean squared log error) and the error scores you get are not comparable to the MSE scores in the paper.  I think since you want to compare to these, the first option I discussed is more sensible.

That takes care of your error metric. How about your loss function?  I'm assuming here that in the paper they trained with MSE loss.  If you use MSE loss with your log-transformed `y_train`, this will not be equivalent to the training process used in the paper, but I think this may be fine.  I suspect that if you were to define a custom loss function which exponentiates prior to computing loss (so as to make the situation more comparable to the training process in the paper), then you might end up removing some/all of the training benefit provided by the log-transformation.  As long as you exponentiate your `y_pred` before computing the error, it is sensible to compare your error scores to those in the paper.

Answer (score 0):

You have a $Y_{true}$

Then you calculated $Y^{log}_{true}$

So, your predictions are $Y^{log}_{pred}$

Then you can calculate the $MSE^{log}$ but it can't be compared with 100 MSE.

So, you can do a - $base^{MSE^{log}}$

*to make it comparabale to 100 MSE.*

A better intuitive approach will be to convert back your $Y^{log}_{pred}$

 i.e. $base^{Y^{log}_{pred}}$

Then calculate the MSE

The inverse of log is just about using *power to the base*

```py
import numpy as np
input = np.array([100, 1000])
log_out = np.log10(input)

input_re = 10**(log_out)
input_re
```

Comment: Your notation is confusing. To rise the value to a log power where the log has no input let me puzzled. Anyway, considering it is log(y_true) or not, I doubt we can just use the inverse using the base: base ^ log(MSE) is correct, because considering the formula "n" is not concerned by the logarithm. So, the MSE obtained isn't log(MSE) but MSE = Sum[log(y_true)-log(y_pred)]/n. As far I know discussing with mathematician, to claim it's equivalent (not equal) to use base^MSE, it must be demonstrated if the function is bijective. A field that I don't master at all.